# MySQL doesn't use the index I expect when my query has a large number of values in `IN` clause

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, sql-in

I have a problem when `IN` clause contains too many values. Consider this query

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT DISTINCT t.entry_id , t.sticky , wd.field_id_104 , t.title
FROM exp_channel_titles AS t
LEFT JOIN exp_channels ON t.channel_id = exp_channels.channel_id
LEFT JOIN exp_channel_data AS wd ON t.entry_id = wd.entry_id
LEFT JOIN exp_members AS m ON m.member_id = t.author_id
INNER JOIN exp_category_posts ON t.entry_id = exp_category_posts.entry_id
INNER JOIN exp_categories ON exp_category_posts.cat_id = exp_categories.cat_id
WHERE t.entry_id !=''
  AND t.site_id IN ('1')
  AND t.entry_date < 1610109517
  AND (t.expiration_date = 0 OR t.expiration_date > 1610109517)
  AND t.entry_id  IN ('0','649','650','651','652','653','654','655')
;
```

if there are few values output is following, which is ok
[image: optimization ok]

but if `IN ('0','649','650','651','652','653','654','655', thousand values)`
query run about 1 minute and explain change to this

[image: failed]

how to fix that?

UPDATE: range_optimizer_max_mem_size had already set to 0 and isn't issue
[image]

Comment: You can put all those valuues in a (temp) table, and change your SQL statement to `... AND t.entry_id IN (SELECT  x FROM temptable)...`

Comment: If they are integers, compare them as integers, not strings.

Comment: Also, you've cut off arguably the most important bit - rows.

Comment: And what's with this selective aliasing?

Comment: @Strawberry I have updated images, please check again. 
I also changed to integers - still the same

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREAT TABLE`.  We can't tell what `PRIMARY` is for `t`.

Comment: Also:  Remove `LEFT JOIN  exp_channels  ON t.channel_id = exp_channels.channel_id`, it serves no function, yet MySQL looks in that table unnecessarily.

Comment: @Luuk - Probably better to put that subquery in a derived table.  `IN (SELECT ...)` may be terribly unoptimal.

Comment: @Strawberry - string column compared to an integer literal is the only "bad" combination.

Answer (score 3):

We have had similar problems at my company when someone runs a query with a very long list of values in an `IN (...)` predicate.

We found that MySQL enforces a limit on memory available to the range optimizer. If the list of values is too long, it exceeds the memory limit, and the optimizer cannot finish its analysis to see if it should use the index. So it gives up and says, "forget it! it's a table-scan for you."

We fix it by setting the MySQL Server configuration value `range_optimizer_max_mem_size=0` which means there is no limit to the memory that the range optimizer can use.

This creates a risk that if someone were to run a query with a million values in the `IN (...)` list, it could use a lot of memory, maybe enough to kill the MySQL Server. But so far the tradeoff is preferable, to allow the optimizer to choose the index.

See documentation:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/range-optimization.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_range_optimizer_max_mem_size

---

Re your comment:

Another common reason for the optimizer to choose to do a table-scan is that it calculates that your conditions match a large enough portion of the table that it's more expensive to use the index than to simply run a table-scan and examine every row.

The threshold for this isn't documented, and it depends on the implementation of the cost-based optimizer, so it might change from version to version. But my observation is that usually if your conditions match more than 20% of the table, the optimizer chooses the table-scan.

You could use an [index hint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html) to tell the optimizer to treat a table-scan as infinitely expensive, so the index is preferred to a table-scan.

Comment: I already did that before posting this thread, that fix didn't help me

Comment: Reply to update: I added `FROM exp_channel_titles AS t USE INDEX (entry_date,expiration_date,site_id)` but seems haven't solved the problem, only the difference explain works faster and no PRIMARY at possible_keys

Comment: How about the relatively safe "Set range_optimizer_max_mem_size to 1% of RAM" instead of the dangerous "0"

Comment: @RickJames So if the list of values in the `IN()` predicate causes the optimizer to use 1.001% of RAM, then it unexpectedly causes the query to do a table-scan?

Answer (score 1):

**Explode-implode.**  This is a classic problem of an inefficient way to write a query.

1. `JOIN` several tables
2. Filter
3. Collapse the results -- usually by `GROUP BY` or `LIMIT`, but `DISTINCT` has the same effect.

So...  Turn the query inside out.

1. Find the ids of the desired rows in `t`
2. `JOIN` that to the rest of the tables.
3. Presumably the `DISTINCT` will not be needed at all.

   ```
    SELECT  t2.entry_id, t2.sticky, wd.field_id_104, t2.title
        FROM ( SELECT id
             FROM  exp_channel_titles
             WHERE entry_id !=''
              AND site_id IN ('1')
              AND entry_date < 1610109517
              AND (expiration_date = 0 OR expiration_date > 1610109517)
              AND entry_id  IN ('0','649','650','651','652','653','654','655')
             ) AS t
        JOIN exp_channel_titles AS t2  USING(id)
        LEFT JOIN  exp_channels  ON t2.channel_id = exp_channels.channel_id
        LEFT JOIN  exp_channel_data AS wd  ON t2.entry_id = wd.entry_id
    ;
   ```

**Another reformulation**

Since there is only one use for `md`, this might be better:

```
SELECT  entry_id,
        sticky,
        ( SELECT wd.field_id_104
            FROM exp_channels  ON t2.channel_id = exp_channels.channel_id
            LEFT JOIN  exp_channel_data AS wd  ON t.entry_id = wd.entry_id
        ) AS field_id_104,
        title
    FROM  exp_channel_titles
    WHERE entry_id !=''
      AND site_id IN ('1')
      AND entry_date < 1610109517
      AND (expiration_date = 0 OR expiration_date > 1610109517)
      AND entry_id  IN ('0','649','650','651','652','653','654','655')
;
```

and have a 5-column index *starting with* `site_id, entry_date`

**Other...**

```
AND (t.expiration_date = 0 OR t.expiration_date > 1610109517)
```

`OR` is not sargeable.  Can you redesign the table to avoid this `OR`?

Without the above reformulation, this may help:

```
INDEX(site_id, entry_date)
```

Also, get rid of these, since they seem to be totally useless:

```
LEFT JOIN exp_channels ON t.channel_id = exp_channels.channel_id
LEFT JOIN  exp_members AS m  ON m.member_id = t.author_id
```

And these may be useless:

```
    INNER JOIN  exp_category_posts  ON t.entry_id = exp_category_posts.entry_id
    INNER JOIN  exp_categories  ON exp_category_posts.cat_id = exp_categories.cat_id
```