# How best to optimise a large where in query?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-optimization

This is a Laravel eloquent query.
The goal is to find all the photos that have the person_id of 1 whilst not having a face with a person_id of 1. Archive of an individuals life not a nefarious big brother thing :)

Any suggestions on speeding this up much appreciated

Relevant Db Structure:

faces

- id
- photo_id (indexed)
- person_id (indexed)

photos

- id

people

- id

person_photo

- photo_id (indexed)
- person_id (indexed)

```
$faces = Face::where('person_id',"=",1)
                ->pluck('photo_id')->toArray();
  
$photos = Photo::with('people','faces.person')
                ->whereHas('people', function($q) {
                    $q->where('people.id','=',1);
                })
                ->whereHas('faces')
                ->whereNotIn('id',$faces)
                ->paginate(21);
```

The query that seems to be the issue is below. Massive array of ids in the wherein. Not sure how to avoid that. Takes about 5 seconds to run.

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `photos`
 where exists (select * from `people` inner join `person_photo` on `people`.`id` = `person_photo`.`person_id` where `photos`.`id` = `person_photo`.`photo_id` and `people`.`id` = 1)
 and exists (select * from `faces` where `photos`.`id` = `faces`.`photo_id` and `faces`.`deleted_at` is null) 
and `id` not in ('massive array of about 20000 ids') and `photos`.`deleted_at` is null
```

Adding Explain as per Bill's comment:
[explain screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz17R.png)

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | people | NULL | const | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | const | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | photos | NULL | index | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | NULL | 48 | 5.00 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | person_photo | NULL | ref | person_photo_photo_id_index,person_photo_person_id_index | person_photo_photo_id_index | 4 | photos.photos.id | 1 | 50.00 | Using where; Start temporary |
| 1 | SIMPLE | faces | NULL | ref | faces_photo_id_index | faces_photo_id_index | 4 | photos.photos.id | 8 | 10.00 | Using index condition; Using where; End temporary |

Comment: Read my answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65645392/20860 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72365471/20860, I guess they might help. But I can't be sure, because you didn't post your table DDL or the EXPLAIN for your query.

Comment: Added the explain.

Comment: Please add the DDL for the tables involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a Laravel user, so I may be barking up the wrong tree here.

Would it not be better to use `whereDoesntHave()` instead of `whereNotIn()`?

```php
$photos = Photo::with('people', 'faces.person')
                ->whereHas('people', function($q) {
                    $q->where('people.id', '=', 1);
                })
                ->whereHas('faces')
                ->whereDoesntHave('faces', function($q) {
                    $q->where('faces.person_id', '=', 1);
                })
                ->paginate(21);
```

Is the `->whereHas('faces')` required? Do you only want photos with at least one face "tagged"?

The `EXPLAIN` output suggests single column indices for `photo_id` and `person_id`, in both the `faces` and `person_photo` tables. These should be composite indices, ideally as PK in one direction, and secondary in the other direction.

Comment: wheredoesnthave sped it up 10 times. Did need whereHas('faces'). That was what I was looking for. I will also add the composite indices, Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. Any time (very few exceptions) you have a junction (many-to-many) table the m2m relationship needs indexing in both directions. Ideally one of them should be the PK, as surrogate PK brings no value, instead they tend to hinder performance.